# What is the limit of the sequence $a_n=(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{4^2})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck on finding the limit of

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Can anybody help?

UPDATE
Is there a solution involving making the fractions like
$$(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2})$$
and using the formula
$$(2^23^24^2...n^2) = (n!)^2$$?

Comment: Sorry for the bad latex before...

Comment: Use $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$ and write each factor as a single fraction.

Answer (score 10):

Since, for every $k$, $$1 - \frac{1}{k^2} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right) = \frac{k-1}{k}\frac{k+1}{k} = \dfrac{\frac{k+1}{k}}{\frac{k}{k-1}}$$ we have by telescoping $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^2}\right)\cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \prod_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{\frac{k+1}{k}}{\frac{k}{k-1}} = \dfrac{\frac{n+1}{n}}{\frac{2}{2-1}} = \frac{n+1}{2n}.$$ So the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

In response to the update, write the factors $1 - 1/k^2$ as $(k-1)(k+1)/k^2$. Doing so, we observe that the product is equal to \begin{align}\prod_{j = 2}^n \frac{(j-1)(j+1)}{j^2} &= \frac{\prod_{j = 2}^n (j-1) \prod_{j = 2}^n (j + 1)}{\prod_{j = 2}^n j^2}\\ &= \frac{(n-1)!\frac{(n+1)!}{2}}{(n!)^2}\\
& = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!}\frac{(n+1)!}{2n!}\\
& = \frac{1}{n}\frac{n+1}{2} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{2n}\end{align}

The result is the same.

Comment: your answer very nice but how to get same value in Bruno Joyal's answer

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio if you see the value of $sin(\pi*z)=0$ at $z=1$, so how can I get the $a_n=1/2$

Comment: @Easy: using the Weierstrass product as Ian did in his deleted answer, we get that the limit is given by $$\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z(1-z^2)}$$ that is easy to handle (no pun intended) through De l'Hopital theorem or other techniques.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: use Euler's formula

$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} = (1-z^2/1^2)(1-z^2/2^2)(1-z^2/3^2)\dots$$

Comment: if you see the value of $sin(\pi*z)=0$ at $z=1$, so how can I get the $a_n=1/2$

Comment: @Easy L'Hôpital's rule! There is a factor of $1-z$ which also vanishes on the RHS...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The function $sin(x)$ has Zeros at $..., - \pi, 0, \pi, 2 \pi, ...$. Therefore one can write:

$sin(\pi x) = ...(x+2 )(x+1)(x)(x-1)(x-2 )... = ...(x^2-2^2 )x(x^2-1^2)...$.

Rearrange this Expression by dividing through $1^22^2...$ and then Substitute $x=1$.

Comment: The function $e^x\sin x$ has the same zeroes...

Comment: This is a nice intuition for the infinite product formula for $\sin(\pi x)$, but it is certainly not a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Write the product as $P= e^{ \log P}$. Using the property of logarithm you get 
$$
e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log (k+1) + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \log (k-1) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k}
$$
Now either use Euler-Maclaurin formula or just the bounds on the sum: $\int_{1}^{n} \log x dx < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k < \int_{1}^{n+1} \log x dx$ and keep in miond that terms like $\frac{1}{n} \to e^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$